# How to detect amount of Java 8 direct memory left?

Tags: java, memory, error-handling, out-of-memory

In JDK8, direct memory can be configured separately, and if you run out of direct memory (such as allocated using ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()), then the JDK will crash your app with a out of direct memory error.

Is there any way to programmatically check how much direct memory is left in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can access information about memory allocated to the JVM your program is running in using `Runtime`.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

long max = runtime.maxMemory();
long free = runtime.freeMemory();
long total = runtime.totalMemory();
```

Comment: This only returns the amount of free heap memory, which is not the same as amount of free direct memory.